Applying for an NSF Math Postdoc at an Institute I’m Employed at that’s Not a Perfect Match
Last year I applied for the NSF Math Postdoc at institute X with sponsor A and was rejected. I got an early offer from institute Y for a postdoc, and I accepted it. Here I have sponsor B, who is excellent, but quite far from my field of research. I have a lot of results and published papers in my field F which is very closely related to the field of professor A, but very far from the field of professor B, which we denote by G. I really enjoy being at institute Y, partially because professor B is excellent and I want to learn about his field. Thus, I am applying for the NSF postdoc at institute Y with sponsor B. After discussing with professor B, he said that I should write a project description that is about my results and their continuations. He suggested that under justification of sponsoring scientist, write something like “In addition to all of these projects in field F, I would like to broaden my horizons to field G, and professor B is an expert in field G and we’ve begun collaborating on a project in this field. Also there are many professors at institute Y who do thing related to field G, and being here is very beneficial to me.”
I wonder if anyone has done this before and if this plan makes any sense, given that I have no results in field G, but many results and collaborations in field F, whereas I only have one 3 month old collaboration with professor B in field G, that has yielded no results yet. Is there any normal way to spin this fact that I am applying for the NSF in a university where there are no people doing math which is closely related to my proposed research in the project description (though there are some doing math under the same umbrella field - that is if I’m doing spectral graph theory, the other researchers here doing something related are doing either microlocal analysis or parabolic PDE’s or extremal combinatorics on graphs as an example).

All you can do is try to make it make sense. It would seem likely that as you learn more about field G that your skills in field F could be brought to bear. You can only apply and see what happens.

It sounds like a reasonable plan, but a lot depends on whether Professor B is interested in this plan :)
On the one hand, postdocs are often very independent, they can work on projects according to their interests and typically require less direct supervision from the PI.
Given that B suggested specifically that you propose your project, that is a good sign that they could see this as a net benefit on their end.
On the other hand, if there is not a "real" research overlap with field G, and if you are not interested in G, that could be a problem for B as research overlap cannot be forced.
You should consider to what extent you get along with B, whether your research philosophies and approaches align, and whether you are applying just for the funding or due to a genuine interest in G.
In summary, regarding your description:

In addition to all of these projects in field F, I would like to broaden my horizons to field G, and professor B is an expert in field G and we’ve begun collaborating on a project in this field. Also there are many professors at institute Y who do thing related to field G, and being here is very beneficial to me.

this sounds like it makes sense, provided you are actually interested in moving (at least part-time) to work on field G, and not just continuing your work in field F.
Postdocs often allocate time to multiple projects, so even if you want to work on G, say, 50% of the time, it sounds like it could be a fit.

I wonder if anyone has done this before and if this plan makes any sense, given that I have no results in field G, but many results and collaborations in field F, whereas I only have one 3 month old collaboration with professor B in field G, that has yielded no results yet.

I have seen many people switch fields for their postdoc, in fact, I think this is common.
Also, 3 months is not a lot of time! Depending on the degree of overlap between F and G, I would expect a period of 1-2 years before real results and publications can come out of the switch.
In my mind, the key question is to what extent have you enjoyed this 3 month stint with professor B? Is it going well in the sense of learning about new research problems? Is it exciting?

Is there any normal way to spin this fact that I am applying for the NSF in a university where there are no people doing math which is closely related to my proposed research in the project description

Maybe it can be thought of more like a collaboration between fields, where you bring the expertise in F, and the university brings the expertise in G, and you bring these together in some way (e.g., different sections about these different angles)?
As Professor B is a key stakeholder here,
it seems unlikely that you would get the position through spinning your interest in F alone, unless Professor B is interested in F for its own sake (I inferred from your description, perhaps incorrectly, that this is not the case.)
If I am understanding the NSF postdoc program specifications, this is effectively a joint proposal between you and B.
Good luck!
